# Missing accents on php mssql result

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a silly question to ask.

I have an Ubuntu 12, PHP 5.4 webserver which I'm planning to migrate to new version. Before my application will be rewritten to latest php I'm testing it on Ubuntu 14, PHP 5.5.9 as I need to use **mssql** for connecting to our MS SQL server.

On my current server when I run a query against the SQL server I get all results as expected. With correct characters and accents.
But on the newer server instead of `č` I get `c`

I checked and compared php config and it seems correct.
`mssql.charset` is identical and set to UTF-8

Thanks

Comment: Check for database collation of new server.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying that but same effect. I had to change the `tds version = 8.0` in freetds.conf. As well as the collation